# Infinitescroll how much is limit on pages element

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, limit, infinite-scroll

I would like to ask about infinitescrolling, example facebook news feed but also a normal wordpress blog which integrate infinitescrolling.

How much elements can support browser on 1 single page before crashing?

I mean, after many scrolling, the page have a lot of posts, I suppose can't show millions posts. How much post a browser can handle?

So if I want implement infinitescrolling, after severall loading, I should think to add a paging for load new page, instaed of appending.

thanks!!

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this question. It depends on the performance of the machine as well as how complex the rendered HTML/CSS is within the repeated elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan One of the reasons for the very simplistic design you see on websites that support this feature.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. I suppose was something like this. So if I want implement this feature on my application, there is not any way to prevent this. If I know machine and suppose rendering it's not complex?

Comment: Nope, there's not much you can do, other than try and make sure the HTML in the repeated elements is as simple and lightweight as you can make it.